# Migrating data from MySQL to DynamoDB

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-dynamodb, database-migration

I Currently have an older application that persists data on a MySQL database. There is now a new application built and running which also has a lot of users and the new app persists all data on a DynamoDb table. The use case for the applications are similar and I plan on merging the two by migrating data from MySQL to DynamDB.

Lets say the app lets users FOLLOW other users. Here is how data in MYSQL is stored.

UserTable

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 2 | Joe |
| 3 | Mike |

FollowTable

| id | receiver | giver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |

This is how my DynamoDB is structured

FollowTable (dynamo)

| giverId(hashkey) | receiverId(sortkey) |
| --- | --- |
| a4e019a5-a4ba-4281-90d9-434a416103a6 | c4e019a5-a4ba-4281-90d9-434a416103a7 |
| a4e019a5-a4ba-4281-90d9-434a416103a6 | d4e019a5-a4ba-4281-90d9-434a416103a8 |

My new application creates the uuids automatically. So, when I migrate the contents form MySQL, the id's 1, 2 and 3 will be replaced by random uuids.

My question is how can I ensure the follow relationship after I migrate when the id's are randomly created.

Comment: You can create random IDs for the users, but you also need a mapping of the old id to the new id when you ingest the data into the Follow Table and use that mapping to update the ids before writing to DDB.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Database Migration Service (DMS)](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) can do this migration for you. While setting migration task you can apply this rule to `FollowTable`.

There is no way to map integer to UUID. But If we get hash_sha256 of giver and receiver, it will produce same hash value. So that data integrity will not loss when migration from MySQL to DynamoDB.

Rules

- 1 select table
- Calculate hash of receiver column and put result into receiverId column
- Calculate hash of giver column and put result into giverId column
- Drop id, giver and receiver columns (Do not migrate this column to DynamoDB)

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "1",
            "rule-name": "1",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "%",
                "table-name": "FollowTable"
            },
            "rule-action": "include",
            "filters": []
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "transformation",
            "rule-id": "2",
            "rule-name": "2",
            "rule-target": "column",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "%",
                "table-name": "FollowTable"
            },
            "rule-action": "add-column",
            "value": "receiverId",
            "expression": "hash_sha256($receiver)",
            "data-type": {
                "type": "string",
                "length": 65
            }
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "transformation",
            "rule-id": "3",
            "rule-name": "3",
            "rule-target": "column",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "%",
                "table-name": "FollowTable"
            },
            "rule-action": "add-column",
            "value": "giverId",
            "expression": "hash_sha256($giver)",
            "data-type": {
                "type": "string",
                "length": 65
            }
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "transformation",
            "rule-id": "4",
            "rule-name": "4",
            "rule-target": "column",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "%",
                "table-name": "FollowTable",
                "column-name": "giver"
            },
            "rule-action": "remove-column"
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "transformation",
            "rule-id": "5",
            "rule-name": "5",
            "rule-target": "column",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "%",
                "table-name": "FollowTable",
                "column-name": "receiver"
            },
            "rule-action": "remove-column"
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "transformation",
            "rule-id": "6",
            "rule-name": "6",
            "rule-target": "column",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "%",
                "table-name": "FollowTable",
                "column-name": "id"
            },
            "rule-action": "remove-column"
        }
    ]
}
```